# Unable to call an Oracle Function

Tags: arrays, function, plsql, oracle11g

I have a package with a function in it like following, which expects one of the parameter which is array.

```
create or replace PACKAGE selected_pkg IS

TYPE NUM_ARRAY IS TABLE OF NUMBER;

FUNCTION get_selected_kml(
  in_layer        IN NUMBER,
  in_solm_id      IN NUMBER,
  in_feature_ids  IN NUM_ARRAY, 
  in_lx           IN NUMBER,
  in_ly           IN NUMBER,
  in_ux           IN NUMBER,
  in_uy           IN NUMBER)
RETURN CLOB;

END selected_pkg;
```

Now I am trying to call the function from following anonymous block :

```
declare
  result CLOB;
  TYPE NUM_ARRAY1 IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
  myarray NUM_ARRAY1 := NUM_ARRAY1 ();
begin
  myarray.extend(3);
  myarray(1) := 1;
  myarray(2) := 5;
  myarray(3) := 9;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'truncate table demoresult';
  result:=SELECTED_PKG.get_selected_kml(103, 19, myarray, 4.11, 56.27, 4.59, 56.39);
  insert into demoresult values(result);
  COMMIT;
end;
```

I am getting error

> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_SELECTED_KML'

Could someone please suggest me, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Alankar

Comment: You're basically hitting [this data compatibility restriction](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#autoId15); although your collection types have the same element type, they are not treated as equivalent. So you're trying to call the function with a different type to the one it's expecting. As Justin's answer shows, you have to use exactly the same collection type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the same array type that your function is expecting

```
declare
  result CLOB;
  myarray selected_pkg.num_array := selected_pkg.num_array();
begin
  myarray.extend(3);
  myarray(1) := 1;
  myarray(2) := 5;
  myarray(3) := 9;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'truncate table demoresult';
  result:=SELECTED_PKG.get_selected_kml(103, 19, myarray, 4.11, 56.27, 4.59, 56.39);
  insert into demoresult values(result);
  COMMIT;
end;
```

Comment: If I use something like below, then also I get error:

    declare
    result CLOB;
    myarray selected_pkg.num_array := selected_pkg.num_array();
    begin
      myarray.extend(3);
      myarray(1) := 1;  myarray(2) := 5;  myarray(3) := 9;
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select column_value from table (cast(myarray AS selected_pkg.num_array))';
      COMMIT;
    end;

Please suggest.

Thanks,
Alan