# Passing Array to Oracle Function

Tags: arrays, oracle, function, plsql, package

I am passing an array to a PL/SQL package function. I am doing this to use this array in a query inside the function which has IN clause.

My declaration of package looks like :

```
create or replace 
PACKAGE selected_pkg IS

  TYPE NUM_ARRAY IS TABLE OF NUMBER;

   FUNCTION get_selected_kml(
      in_layer        IN NUMBER,
     in_id      IN NUMBER,
      in_feature_ids  IN selected_pkg.NUM_ARRAY,
      in_lx           IN NUMBER,
      in_ly           IN NUMBER,
      in_ux           IN NUMBER,
      in_uy           IN NUMBER
      )
    RETURN CLOB;

END selected_pkg;
```

In my PL/SQL function I am firing a query like following

```
select a.id, a.geom  from Table_FIELD a  where  a.id in (select * from table (in_feature_ids)) and  sdo_filter(A.GEOM,mdsys.sdo_geometry(2003,4326,NULL,mdsys.sdo_elem_info_array(1,1003,3), mdsys.sdo_ordinate_array(0,57,2.8,59)),'querytype= window') ='TRUE'
```

The same query runs fine if I run it from anonymous block like

```
CREATE TYPE num_arr1 IS TABLE OF NUMBER;

declare
    myarray num_arr1 := num_arr1(23466,13396,14596);
BEGIN
    FOR i IN (select a.id, a.geom  from Table_FIELD a  where  a.id in (select * from table (myarray)) and  sdo_filter(A.GEOM,mdsys.sdo_geometry(2003,4326,NULL,mdsys.sdo_elem_info_array(1,1003,3), mdsys.sdo_ordinate_array(0,57,2.8,59)),'querytype= window') ='TRUE'
    loop
       dbms_output.put_line(i.id);
    end loop;
end;
```

If I try to run it by calling function as below

```
--Running function from passing array for IDs
declare
  result CLOB;
  myarray selected_pkg.num_array := selected_pkg.num_array(23466,13396,14596);
begin
    result:=SELECTED_PKG.get_selected_kml(3, 19, myarray, 0.0,57.0,2.8,59);
end;
```

I am getting error

```
ORA-00904: "IN_FEATURE_IDS": invalid identifier
```

Could someone please help me understand the cause of it?

Thanks,
Alan

Comment: Alex,Yes I got that fixed in the question above(error caused in copy-pasting). However I am running it right.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot query a type declared in plsql in a sql query, as the sql engine doesn't recognise it.

Your first example works because you have declared the type numarr1 in the database, whereas the type selected_pkg.num_array is declared in a package.

Good summary [here](http://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/collection-types.html)

Comment: Stevo, Could you please suggest how could I achieve the functionality?

Comment: @AlanShar see the answer from Alex Poole.

Answer (score 2):

I can't quite recreate the error you're getting; the anonymous block doesn't refer to `in_feature_ids`, and the package ought to only report that if it doesn't recognise it on compilation rather than at runtime - unless you're using dynamic SQL. Without being able to see the function body I'm not sure how that's happening.

But you can't use a PL/SQL-defined type in an SQL statement. At some point the `table(in_feature_ids)` will error; I'm getting an ORA-21700 when I tried it, which is a new one for me, I'd expect ORA-22905. Whatever the error, you have to use a type defined at schema level, not within the package, so this will work (skipping the spatial stuff for brevity):

```
CREATE TYPE num_array IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE selected_pkg IS
    FUNCTION get_selected_kml(
        in_layer        IN NUMBER,
        in_id           IN NUMBER,
        in_feature_ids  IN NUM_ARRAY,
        in_lx           IN NUMBER,
        in_ly           IN NUMBER,
        in_ux           IN NUMBER,
        in_uy           IN NUMBER
    ) RETURN CLOB;
END selected_pkg;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY selected_pkg IS
    FUNCTION get_selected_kml(
        in_layer        IN NUMBER,
        in_id           IN NUMBER,
        in_feature_ids  IN NUM_ARRAY,
        in_lx           IN NUMBER,
        in_ly           IN NUMBER,
        in_ux           IN NUMBER,
        in_uy           IN NUMBER
    ) RETURN CLOB IS
    BEGIN
        FOR i IN (select * from table(in_feature_ids)) LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i.column_value);
        END LOOP;
        RETURN null;
    END get_selected_kml;
END selected_pkg;
/
```

... and calling that also using the schema-level type:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
    result CLOB;
    myarray num_array := num_array(23466,13396,14596);
begin
    result:=SELECTED_PKG.get_selected_kml(3, 19, myarray, 0.0,57.0,2.8,59);
end;
/

23466
13396
14596

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Also note that you have to use exactly the same type, not just one that looks the same, as discussed [in a recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16234575/266304). You wouldn't be able to call your function with a variable of `num_arr1` type, for example; they look the same on the surface but to Oracle they are different and incompatible.